# Find last data (status) with datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck in situation in which I have a data like

```
studentId Marks marksgotOn
1         10    2019-12-01
1         10    2019-12-01
2         35    2019-12-02
3         35    2019-12-02
4         90    2019-12-03
```

I need to find when student got last `marksGotOn`

```
SELECT StudentId, CASE WHEN Marks BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 'Fail'
  WHEN Marks BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN 'Pass' 
  WHEN Marks >=90 THEN 'Excellent' ELSE '' END AS ResultStatus
FROM Student
```

but I need to find when student change their `lastResultStatus` time.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: i expected when students last status change on

Comment: you can add markgoton column to your query

Comment: please share your expected output from your data

Comment: I don't see a column `lastResultStatus` in your query? Or is this what you are trying to establish?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the value from the previous row and compare with current one. We are using `PARTITION` to group the results by student and ordering by `marksGotOn`.

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT StudentId
         ,CASE WHEN Marks BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 'Fail'WHEN Marks BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN 'Pass' WHEN Marks >=90 THEN 'Excellent' ELSE '' END AS ResultStatus
         ,marksGotOn 
    FROM Student
)
SELECT *
      ,IIF(LAG(ResultStatus) OVER(PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY marksGotOn) <> ResultStatus, 'Changed', 'Not Changed')
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY StudentId
        ,marksGotOn
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @gotqn's answer, in order to get the latest date on which a student's status changed:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT StudentId
         ,CASE WHEN Marks BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 'Fail'WHEN Marks BETWEEN 30 AND 35 THEN 'Pass' WHEN Marks >=90 THEN 'Excellent' ELSE '' END AS ResultStatus
         ,marksGotOn 
    FROM Student
)
,
GradeChanges as
(
SELECT *
      ,IIF(LAG(ResultStatus) OVER(PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY marksGotOn) <> ResultStatus, 'Changed', 'Not Changed') as GradeChange
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY StudentId
        ,marksGotOn
)

select
    StudentId,
    max(marksgotOn) as LastGradeChange
where
    GradeChange = 'Changed'
group by
    StudentId
```